# Ejabberd clustering .erlang cookie accessible by owner only

Tags: cluster-computing, ejabberd

After cluster set up, I changed into the `ejabberd/bin` directory in my terminal. Then I enter this command

```
erl -sname ejabberd@test -mnesia extra_db_nodes "['ejabberd@testone']" -s mnesia
```

after this command I got this error in my terminal

> {error_logger,{{2013,10,15},{17,3,14}},"Cookie file /root/.erlang.cookie must be accessible by owner only",[]}.

Answer (score 4):

From the [Erlang docs](http://www.erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/distributed.html#id83696):

> At start-up, a node has a random atom assigned as its magic cookie and the cookie of other nodes is assumed to be nocookie. The first action of the Erlang network authentication server (auth) is then to read a file named $HOME/.erlang.cookie. If the file does not exist, it is created. The UNIX permissions mode of the file is set to octal 400 (read-only by user) and its contents are a random string. An atom Cookie is created from the contents of the file and the cookie of the local node is set to this using erlang:set_cookie(node(), Cookie). This also makes the local node assume that all other nodes have the same cookie Cookie.

You appear to be running as root. You'll need to ensure that `/root/.erlang.cookie` is owned by root and has mode 600 (not read, write, or execute by anyone besides root).